# Casting a binding<Double> to type Int - Swift UI

Tags: casting, binding, swiftui

I'm trying to cast a value of Binding to an Int value however it always fails on the casting.

It needs to be an int to generate the random number.

```
func randomise(startNumber: Int, endNumber: Int) -> Int{
    let startNum = $value.startNumber
    let endNum = $value.endNumber
    let generated = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(endNum - startNum)) + UInt32(startNum)
        
    return Int(generated)
}
```

How does the converting of a Binding to a standard type work?

Here is the class that the binding Observable object is created.

```
final class Value:ObservableObject {
    @Published var startNumber: Double = 0
    @Published var endNumber: Double = 5000
}
```

The two errors generated:

```
Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Binding<Double>' conform to 'BinaryInteger'
Referencing operator function '-' on 'BinaryInteger' requires that 'Binding<Double>' conform to 'BinaryInteger'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ObservedObject is a property wrapper around the actual object.  So, to access the non-binding values of those properties, you could use `wrappedValue`:

```
func randomise(startNumber: Int, endNumber: Int) -> Int{
        
        
        let startNum = $value.startNumber
        let endNum = $value.endNumber
        let generated = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(endNum.wrappedValue - startNum.wrappedValue)) + UInt32(startNum.wrappedValue)
            
        return Int(generated)
    }
```

OR

You could get rid of the `$` when you access your value variable, removing the Binding that way:

```
func randomise(startNumber: Int, endNumber: Int) -> Int{
        
        
        let startNum = value.startNumber
        let endNum = value.endNumber
        let generated = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(endNum - startNum)) + UInt32(startNum)
            
        return Int(generated)
    }
```